# Работа с API. Функция fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

На сайте есть поле input куда пользователь вводит данные по вин или госномеру. После корректно введённых данных должна открываться страница с данными об автомобили с сайта api-cloud rsa.

```
document.querySelector('s-board__search-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let data = document.querySelector('.s-board__search-input').value;
    document.querySelector('.proverka-out').innerHTML = data;
})


async function getResponce() {
    let response = await fetch('https://api-cloud.ru/api/rsa.php?token=3f46a2c66304f0da725f637ebff1deff')
    let content = await response.json()

    let list = document.querySelector('.textcols')

    let key;
    for (key in content) {
        list.innerHTML += `
        <div class="textcols-item">
        <ul>
            <li class="s-app__list-head_1">Госномер: ${content[key].regnum}</li>
            <li class="s-app__list-head_1">Марка: ${content[key].brandmodel}</li>
            <li class="s-app__list-head_1">Мощность: ${content[key].power}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="textcols-item">
        <ul>
            <li class="s-app__list-head_1">Vin: ${content[key].vin}</li>
            <li class="s-app__list-head_1">Модель: ${content[key].brandmodel}</li>
            <li class="s-app__list-head_1">Номер СТС: ${content[key].stsNumber}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    `

    
    }
}
getResponce()
```

Сайт не выдаёт ни HTML разметку, ни данные с api. Что делать?

Comment: Первые 4 строки не относятся к api

Comment: Смотрите ошибки в консоли

Comment: нигде не вызывается метод `getResponce`